# php On form submission action value set to nothing until second form submission then sets to value

Tags: php, ajax, forms, action

I am currently a student and have been dabbling with php for the past few weeks. I am going to first try explain my problem in simple english and then provide some code to show the complexity of the problem.

I am dealing with a product ordering screen whereby a user first selects the product category from a drop down list populated from the database.

Upon selection of the product category drop down, the product name drop down list is populated from the database using an ajax query.

**index.php**

```
$(".Product_Category").change(function()
{
  var id=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'id='+ id;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_product.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
      $(".Product_Name").html(html);
    }
  });
});
```

The ajax_product script basically receives the id of the category selected and then gets the products associated with it from the database and then returns the product names to the success: function of the ajax statement in index.php as such.

**ajax_product**

```
echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
```

Once the user selects a product from the dropdown and clicks on the submit button the form submits the action below:

**Form**

`<form method="post" class="form-horizontal " action="Place_Order_3.php?action=add&code=<?php echo($Prod_Name_Succ)?>">`

The $Prod_Name_Succ variable is set to the product id selected in the drop down ie. $Prod_Name_Succ=$_POST['Product_Name'].

Now here in lies my issue, finally. 
As far as I understand there is a cause and effect relationship problem here, because when I submit the form for the first time the action code is set to "" even though I have selected a product from the dropdown. Upon the second form submission variable $Prod_Name_Succ is now set to the product id selected in the dropdown and I can now add that product to the shopping cart.

So it appears to me that the form cannot add the $Prod_Name_Succ code to action until it has been through the form submission function ie. `if(!empty($_GET["action"]) { }` and so I can never add the product on the first form submission.

I have tried using a `$_Session` to store the id and setting it to nothing again but the same problem seems to still apply.

Comment: Please provide the form HTML

Comment: input data where are?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem yesterday, so there is no need. Basically I just bypassed the action code and just used the $_POST as the code for the product selected in the drop down but not via the action method at all. 
Thanks for your replies though, I'm not posting all my code for this section cause there is simply too much.